# how to resolve error error: invalid choice: 'mysql_db' on long2ice / synch

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, clickhouse

Am using long2ice/synch tools for mysql to clickhouse data replication on a specific table, but when am running the below command `> synch --alias mysql_db etl -h` getting error

> synch --alias mysql_db etl -h usage: synch [-h] [-c CONFIG]
> [--version] {etl,produce,consume} ... synch: error: invalid choice:
> 'mysql_db' (choose from 'etl', 'produce', 'consume')

How to resolve the above error.

configuration file as it is, below as am mention

```
 db_type: mysql
    alias: mysql_db # must be unique
    broker_type: redis # current support redis and kafka
    server_id: 1
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3306
    user: root
    password: "12345"
    # optional, auto get from `show master status` when empty
    init_binlog_file:
    # optional, auto get from `show master status` when empty
    init_binlog_pos:
    skip_dmls: # dmls to skip
    skip_delete_tables: # tables skip delete, format with schema.table
    skip_update_tables: # tables skip update, format with schema.table
    databases:
      - database: test
```

Anything i am missing above configuration.

Thanks,
Bimal.

Comment: Link of the tools: https://github.com/long2ice/synch

Comment: you just copy-paste from official readme
which just show "usage"
you not need to use "-h" at the end
so, just use `synch --alias mysql_db etl` should enough for you
you need

Comment: trying to run using rhis command " synch --alias mysql_db etl " getting same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

try to use following config

```yaml
core:
  debug: true
source_dbs:
  - db_type: mysql
    alias: mysql_db # must be unique
    broker_type: redis # current support redis and kafka
    server_id: 1
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3306
    user: root
    password: "12345"
```

and run

```sh
synch --alias mysql_db etl
```

Comment: No change has made at above configuration that you have mention. It is same as previous configuration. And i have tried with above configuration getting same error before. Error : " synch: error: invalid choice: 'mysql_db' (choose from 'etl', 'produce', 'consume') "